# Query string not being executed properly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-core

I'm using [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-3.0) to execute a query:

```
string query = "select distinct c.Id, a.FirstName, a.LastName 
    from dbo.Customer c, dbo.Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping ccrm, dbo.Address a 
    where ccrm.CustomerRole_Id = 14 AND ccrm.Customer_Id = c.Id and a.Email = c.Email;";
string dbConnection = "Data Source=..."; // this is working, I tested it
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);    
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

// ...Parse reader...
```

The string query was tested in a DBMS and I should get 6 results, but I get 0 results when I use it with `SqlCommand`, the connection is working fine, I tested it, I also tested it with a simpler querys (e.g. `select Id from dbo.Customer`), and they also work good. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? The problem must be the query string, the aliases perhaps?

PS.: I'm going to use, of course, parameters, but for this example it would just add clutter. I'm also considering using LINQ but for now I just need this to work as is.

Comment: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot your query?

Comment: Can you please test by adding below statement - 
`com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`

Comment: @DanielMann, it's what I described, I tested the connection, which is working, and I tried a simpler query, which is also working, so the problem must be in the query itself, perhaps the aliases.

Comment: is this executed in different instances or databases an in one you get 6 rows and in the other 0?

Comment: @Sibgath will do

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits it's the same db

Comment: @anastaciu the query seems to work absolutley fine - I just executed it (with modified connection and table etc.) and it returned the expected rows. I guess the join is messing up the result. Might be you should use a left loin instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this query

```
var  query = "select distinct c.Id, a.FirstName, a.LastName from Customer c 
left  join Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping ccrm  on  c.Id = ccrm.Customer_Id 
 left  join Address a on c.Email = a.Email
 where ccrm.CustomerRole_Id = 14;"
```

Comment: not necessarily - even if not recommended, a join like `ccrm.Customer_Id = c.Id and a.Email = c.Email` is valid as well

Comment: I just offer to try

Comment: The original is an inner join query, so I guess one table does not contain the key used in the othe rtable

Comment: @anastaciu  You used inner joins. When some of the columns have null value the whole record will be omited. In this case you have to use outter joins - left or right.